# How to change the Spinner font color?

Tags: android, spinner

I'm having an issue with the Droid X phones where users say that the font color turns out to be white in the spinner, making it invisible unless the users highlight the items.  No other phones seem to have this problem.  I was going to try to force the font to be black to see if that helps.  How can I do that?

Here's how I'm currently populating the spinner.  It seems like the `simple_spinner_item` is broken on Droid X's.

```
String spin_arry[] = new String[str_vec.size()];
str_vec.copyInto(spin_arry);
ArrayAdapter adapter =
    new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spin_arry);
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I'm going to use `Spinner` project sample from Android SDK for next code examples.

---

**Code**:

First, you need to create you custom adapter which will intercept the creation of views in drop down list:

```
static class CustomArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context ctx, T [] objects)
    {
        super(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects);
    }

    //other constructors

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        //we know that simple_spinner_item has android.R.id.text1 TextView:         

        /* if(isDroidX) {*/
            TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);//choose your color :)         
        /*}*/

        return view;

    }
}
```

Then you create adapter in your code like this:

```
 String [] spin_arry = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Planets);        
 this.mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, spin_arry);
```

---

**Explanation:**

Because `CustomArrayAdapter` knows that we use android's built-in layout resource, it also knows that text will be placed in `TextView` with id `android.R.id.text1`. That's why it can intercept the creation of views in drop down list and change text color to whatever color is needed.

---

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: better solution, modify this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409871/how-to-increase-spinner-item-font-size

Answer (score 7):

Simple and Crisp ...

```java
private OnItemSelectedListener OnCatSpinnerCL = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
  public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(5);
  }

  public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
  }
};
```

Comment: This causes the TextView to be null when you rotate your device.

Answer (score 7):

write a `R.layout.simplespinneritem：`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The ID is `android:id="@android:id/text1"`, set the color of font and background.

```
ArrayAdapter adapter =
  new ArrayAdapter(this,packagename.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spin_arry);
```

Comment: How do you use this if the spinner's items are loaded from <string-array> using the entries attribute?

Answer (score 3):

```
public class ee extends Activity{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ww);
addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();

}
public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection(){

    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    array.add("item0");
    Spinner spinner1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
    spinner1= (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    spinner1= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, array);
    spinner1.setAdapter(mAdapter);

}  
}
```

and in xml res/layout add new xml file: type layout, spinner

(in spinner_item.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="#00f0ff" />
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to sasad's reply, make a copy of that file, which you can find in your Android folder, in your project, change the text color of the TextView in that file, and use that layout while initializing the Adapter instead of android's.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach too wherein you add 2 new Layout Resource Files

1. Custom_spinner_list_item
2. Custom_spinner_dropdown_item

and use them in the code .

```
String spin_arry[] = new String[str_vec.size()];
str_vec.copyInto(spin_arry);
ArrayAdapter adapter =
    new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.custom_simple_spinner_item, spin_arry);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_spinner_dropdown_item);
```

**custom_spinner_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roman"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp">

</TextView>
```

**custom_spinner_dropdown_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:fontFamily="@font/roman"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textAlignment="textStart"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="14sp">

</TextView>
```

Happy Coding !! :)

Answer (score -1):

make your own layout xml file, and give a android:textColor="#000" for black text

Answer (score -1):

**Here is more appropriate way guys,**

First find the "simple_spinner_item.xml" file in your system,
Follow the below path,
C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms[android-23]\data\res\layout

Now copy the content of "simple_spinner_item.xml" file

Second create the custom_spinner.xml file in your project res\layout folder

and paste the copied content in recently created file

Here is the sample:

res\layout\custom_spinner.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:textAlignment="inherit"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:id="@android:id/text1" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

Here is the set adapter code:

```
Spinner ddlArea = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.ddlArea);

ddlArea.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_spinner, areaList));
```

Where areaList is the List

Thanks,
Ejaz Waquif

Comment: This is not an answer on the question