# Spinner has Grey Text, why? How can I change it to default text colour instead?

Tags: android, android-layout

I implemented this kind of thing in my app but can't figure out why it turns text grey, like in the photo...

anyone know why? and I how do i change it to default text colour? the spinner in my layout file looks like black text.. but when I run it, it is grey just like in this sample.

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/12/custom-spinner-with-icon.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to create a custom adapter to hook into the creation of the views. Similar SO question with some useful info for you: [Change spinner font color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361604/how-to-change-the-spinner-font-color)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I really get your question, but if you want to change the text color of the items of the spinner, just add `android:textColor="your color here"` to the TextView of row.xml.

Answer (score 0):

yeah I think my question was flawed.. seems like maybe this light grey is default color.. but it looks horrible (unreadable almost) on my galaxy s2.. on emulator it looks ok, but a little light..

it is first spinner i ever created...

so I solved it by hard-coding a darker grey... but I don't like hard coding because I am unsure if some android devices would skin the background of the spinner to some color that makes a dark grey unreadable?