# ListView is not in focus?

Tags: android, listview, layout

I have a `ListView` inside a `LinearLayout` that is not "in focus" it is a somewhat grayed out, yet fully functional, if I click on an item it is selectable yet everything stays the same light grey color. how can I change this so that it is "in focus" (or whatever the term may be?)

[image: android VD with problem]

xml file of layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >            

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:text="Save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:text="Cancel" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/assemblersSpinners"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/assembliesSpinner"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


    </LinearLayout>

<ListView
        android:id="@+id/assemblyPartsListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

onCreate code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_premade_assembly);

    //lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.assemblyPartsListView);
    //lv.setAdapter(new CustomPLNViewAdapter(this, partLotNumberList, partNames));
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.assemblyPartsListView);
    if(!lv.hasFocus()){
        lv.setFocusable(true);
    }
```

custom adapter for listview

```
public class CustomCreateAssemblyViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> partLotNumbersArrayList;
private static ArrayList<String> partNames;
private static String selected;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

private Context myContext;

public CustomCreateAssemblyViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> results, ArrayList<String> parts){
    partLotNumbersArrayList = results;
    partNames = parts;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    myContext = context;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return partLotNumbersArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_assembly_parts, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.partName);
        holder.spinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.LotNumbers);
        convertView.setTag(holder);         
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(partNames.get(position));        

    ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position));          
    adp1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    //set the adapter to the spinnner
    holder.spinner.setAdapter(adp1);        

    //if there is only one other part besides "" then set that as default part
    if(partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position).size() == 2){
        holder.spinner.setSelection(1);
    }   

    holder.spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ///ViewOrderlineAssemblyActivity.assembly.addPart(new Part((String)holder.txtName.getText(), ""));
            //Log.v("OnNothingSelected", (String)holder.txtName.getText());
        }

    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    Spinner spinner;
}
```

adapter is set in this class

```
class LoadAssemblyParts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(CreateAssemblyActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading assembly parts. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All orders from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {           
        partLotNumberList = dbUtils.getAllAssemblyParts(assemblyName);
        partNames = dbUtils.getAllAssemblyPartNames(assemblyName);
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all orders
        pDialog.dismiss();  

        lv.setAdapter(new CustomCreateAssemblyViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(), partLotNumberList, partNames));
        lv.requestFocus();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Share your onCreate code where you have initialized your spinner. Also, see this if it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133718/spinner-has-grey-text-why-how-can-i-change-it-to-default-text-colour-instead

Comment: shared code and and my adapter

Answer (score 0):

you need the id of the listview

in oncreate

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.your listview id here)
```

and then you do this....

```
if(!lv.hasFocus()){
            lv.setFocusable(true);
            lv.requestFocus();
          }
```

Comment: that did not fix the issue, it is still doing it. do I need to do it for each item in the `ListView`?

Comment: tried doing it to each individual item in the listview (each spinner and textview) and still no change.

Comment: But thisdoes not mean the Listview is focused.For focussing you have to use

    mListView.requestFocus();
For changing focus on click of a button you can place the code on onClick() of the button.                                  i would just call lv.requestFocus() after you initialize in oncreate.

Comment: I tried your code edit and still no change, even if I select the listview it will not come into focus, I added more info the question if that is helpful

Comment: lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.assemblyPartsListView);
    if(!lv.hasFocus()){
        lv.setFocusable(true);
    } try request focus here in oncreate?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/permanenttan/archive/2009/04/29/setting-the-initial-focus-to-a-listview-item.aspx                  the core idea here is the same

Comment: yep did it in oncreate and still no change, I'll check out that blog

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out this has nothing to do with focus and just the fact that android likes to lay things out weirdly. I had to change the adapter to set the text color. Here is the solution.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adp1=new ArrayAdapter<String>(myContext, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, partLotNumbersArrayList.get(position)){
            @Override
            public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView,android.view.ViewGroup parent){
                View v = convertView;
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);               
                TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                text.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                return view;
            }
        };
```