# How should I increase the spinner list item font size?

Tags: android, spinner

This is my spinner's code:

```
Spinner food = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> foodadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
        this, R.array.item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
foodadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);        
food.setAdapter(foodadapter);
```

This is a part of the layout file where I have created the spinner:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1" />
```

This is the `item_array`:

```
<resources>
    <string name="item_picker">Select an iten</string>
    <string-array name="item_array">
        <item>Pizza</item>
        <item>Burger</item>
        <item>Sandwiches</item>
        <item>Bread</item>
        <item>Pastries</item>
        <item>Snackers</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Note: I do not want a `simple_spinner_dropdown_item`.

I just want to increase the size of the list items. How can I do that?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Save the below xml as spinner_layout.xml in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:textSize="13sp"
/>
```

change the textSize which you want.
and use the below adapter code to fill it.

```
Spinner food = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> foodadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.item_array, R.layout.spinner_layout);
foodadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
food.setAdapter(foodadapter);
```

Comment: this is increasing the size of spinner item after selected

Comment: ...but not the items . example : items are pizza ,burger,sandwiches , etc. they are not increasing in font size, but after selection  the value it shows in the spinner gets increased

Comment: set spinner's  android:layout_width="fill_parent"

Comment: could you please solve this?          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411543/how-to-get-spinner-value-depending-upon-the-other-spinner

Answer (score 32):

### Via XML Only

*Just to help others in case they are statically setting their Spinner entries in XML.*

The above answers work if you're creating your *Spinner* via code but if you're setting your Spinner entries via XML, i.e. using `android:entries`, then you can adjust the text size and other attributes with the following two theme settings:

#### In your `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

        <!-- For the resting Spinner style -->
        <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerItemStyle
        </item> 

        <!-- For each individual Spinner list item once clicked on -->
        <item name="android:spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
            @style/spinnerDropDownItemStyle
        </item>

    </style>

    <style name="spinnerItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

    <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">
        <item name="android:padding">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Great idea however this does not work for me on a 2.3.x device.

Comment: @rekire Good to know. I tested on 4+. That's too bad, because I find it much cleaner.

Comment: Anyone know why it doesn't work if directly set style in spinner? <Spinner ... style="@sytle/spinnerItemStyle" />

Comment: I really like this idea.  I tried the code in both styles.xml and  v11\styles.xml, and tested on an Android 4.1 emulator and an Android 4.2 device. It does not work on either of them.  I am wondering what I am missing.

Comment: @Hong It didn't work correctly for me first time either. Apparently, you need to set parent style for them as well, like:<style name="spinnerItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">  and <style name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.DropDownItem.Spinner">

Comment: does it set spinner text size for all spinners in the app? what would make it applicable to *some* spinners (via XML), but not all?

Comment: The spinner is a ViewGroup, which is why the style of the spinner does not affect the text in the way that we would hope. The TextView is dynamically created by the adapter, and it is unrelated to the style of the Spinner.

Comment: For AppCompat theme just remove `android:` like this `<item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/mySpinnerItemStyle</item>`

Answer (score 3):

The above solutions are all hard coded in  the xml.

There is an alternative solution which allows you to change it programmatically.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11494962/5089713
Once you have the TextView, you can do whatever with it, for instance change the font size.

your code then looks like

```
Spinner food = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

CharSequence[] strings = getActivity().getResources().getTextArray(R.array.item_array);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> foodadapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, strings){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view =super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView=(TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            // do whatever you want with this text view
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            return view;
        }
    };

foodadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);        
food.setAdapter(foodadapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private OnItemSelectedListener spinner = new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
       ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(10);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to increase the size, that the dropdown is good touchable, then you simply can change the *simple_spinner_item* to *simple_spinner_dropdown_item*:

```
 ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.item_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                                                       ---------------------------^
```