# How to get spinner value depending upon the other spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have two spinner item. One is my Day spinner , another is my Month Spinner.
If I select month February from month spinner and if I select day as 30 ,it should not be done.

Another example: month April has 30 days , so if someone selects Month as April and day as 31st  ,then it is not correct. Please tell me how to do get the value of one spinner corresponding to the value of another spinner.

Here is my code where I have the two spinners:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
 /*************day spinner**********/

        Spinner day  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dayadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.item_day, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        dayadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        day.setAdapter(dayadapter);

        /*****************month spinner**********************/


        Spinner month  = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> monthadapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
                this, R.array.item_month, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        monthadapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_layout);
        month.setAdapter(monthadapter);


}}
```

My Xml where the spinners are defined :

```
    <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3" />
   <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5" />
```

my spinner_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textColor="#000000"
          android:textSize="12pt"
/>
```

my day array

```
<string name="day_picker">Select an iten</string>
<string-array name="item_day">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
     <item>7</item>
    <item>8</item>
    <item>9</item>
    <item>10</item>
    <item>11</item>
    <item>12</item>
     <item>13</item>
    <item>14</item>
    <item>15</item>
    <item>16</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>18</item>
     <item>19</item>
    <item>20</item>
    <item>21</item>
    <item>22</item>
    <item>23</item>
    <item>24</item>
     <item>25</item>
    <item>26</item>
    <item>27</item>
    <item>28</item>
    <item>29</item>
    <item>30</item>
    <item>31</item>

</string-array>
```

my month array

```
<resources>
    <string name="month_picker">Select an item</string>
    <string-array name="item_month">
        <item>January</item>
        <item>February</item>
        <item>March</item>
        <item>April</item>
        <item>May</item>
        <item>June</item>
         <item>July</item>
        <item>August</item>
        <item>September</item>
        <item>October</item>
        <item>November</item>
        <item>December</item>
         </string-array>
</resources>
```

If I select any month I want to get corresponding no. of days automatically in day-spinner
Note: I do not want any error message  after clicking a button. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
month.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<String> s = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_day));
            if (pos == 0 || pos == 2 || pos == 4 || pos == 8 || pos == 9
                    || pos == 11) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> dayadapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(Latlondemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,s);
                day.setAdapter(dayadapter);
            } else if (pos == 1) {
                s = s.subList(0,28);                    
                ArrayAdapter<String> dayadapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(Latlondemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,s);
                day.setAdapter(dayadapter);
            } else {
                s = s.subList(0,30);                    
                ArrayAdapter<String> dayadapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(Latlondemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,s);
                day.setAdapter(dayadapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Comment: what does LatLonDemo class do?

Comment: Sorry i have implement in this class so you may write your class name instead of LatLonDemo.

Comment: its okay.. you helped me a lot :)

Comment: Can you solve this.. i have full trust on you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449902/calling-a-spinner-from-another-class-giving-exception#comment13495291_10449902 please check the answer , i tried that and it didnt solve.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple. Put a OnItemSelectedListener() on the month spinner, adding your own listener which initializes the day spinner with the correct values

Comment: +1. And the OP can do without the gigantic day array too:-) Initializing such an array programmatically would be easier on the eyes...