# Second spinner depends from first spinner (Xamarin VS)

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, spinner

I found many similar questions which most I've seen are in Java, the thing is I don't know how to convert a Java code into C# Xamarin.

Here is the code I found: [from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10411543/how-to-get-spinner-value-depending-upon-the-other-spinner?rq=1)

```
   month.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int pos, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            List<String> s = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_day));
            if (pos == 0 || pos == 2 || pos == 4 || pos == 8 || pos == 9
                    || pos == 11) {
                ArrayAdapter<String> dayadapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(Latlondemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,s);
                day.setAdapter(dayadapter);
            } else if (pos == 1) {
                s = s.subList(0,28);                    
                ArrayAdapter<String> dayadapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(Latlondemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,s);
                day.setAdapter(dayadapter);
            } else {
                s = s.subList(0,30);                    
                ArrayAdapter<String> dayadapter = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(Latlondemo.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,s);
                day.setAdapter(dayadapter);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

I'm specifically referring to this line:

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item_day));
```

What is its C# counterpart?

Here are my codes so far:

```
        spinner1 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner1);
        spinner2 = FindViewById<Spinner>(Resource.Id.spinner2);

        var adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
                this, Resource.Array.building_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);
        var adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.CreateFromResource(
                this, Resource.Array.level_array, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerItem);

        adapter1.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        adapter2.SetDropDownViewResource(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleSpinnerDropDownItem);
        spinner1.Adapter = adapter1;
        spinner2.Adapter = adapter2;
        spinner1.ItemClick += (sender, e) => {

        // code here

        };
```

String resource:

```
<resources>
  <string-array name="building_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
  </string-array>
  <string-array name="level_array">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# counterpart is

```
var arr = Resources.GetStringArray(Resource.Array.building_array);
```

This is valid in a Android Context, e.g. your Activity, because `Resources` is a property of it.

If you want it to be a `List<sting>`, just append a `.ToList()` (needs: `using System.Linq;`) to the call.