# Changing the text size of a spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner, android-spinner

I am a beginner in Android programming.

I am trying to change the text size of the spinner as mentioned in some question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409871/how-to-increase-spinner-item-font-size). I have created `my_spinner_style.xml` in `res/values/` as below:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerTarget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="13sp"
/>
```

and used an adapter like this:

```
spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.answers,android.R.layout.my_spinner_style);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and also tried creating `style.xml` in the layout folder. My adapter does not recognize `my_spinner_style`. Have I placed it in the wrong directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `R.layout.my_spinner_style`, remove the **`android`** at the start, that makes it point to the Android package and not your project.

Note the R you're importing is your project's Resources, saying android.R points to Android resources, not your project.

**// Edit this is how you have sizes based on the screen size**

**dimens.xml** This is under values (default):

```
<resources>

<!-- Font sizes in SP -->
<dimen name="small_font">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="big_font">20sp</dimen>

</resources>
```

**dimens.xml** this is under my values-fr (French, in your case, you'll have screen size qualifiers)

```
<resources>

<!-- Font sizes in SP -->
<dimen name="small_font">16sp</dimen>
<dimen name="big_font">22sp</dimen>

</resources>
```

Then in my `TextView` for example, this is my font size:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="@dimen/small_font">

    </TextView>
```

Now the font size is dependent on the language (English goes to **`values`** and French goes to **`values-fr`**) You should have the same thing but using screen size qualifiers.

Comment: I have written different xml files for different screen sizes. The change in text size of the spinner changes in all layouts. Since am hardcoding the size to 26sp it remains same in all size. Is there anyway to change this ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the qualifiers to decide which layout to load based on the screen size. Create the same folders for the `values` folder, and place a `dimens.xml` there (It's of type `resources`). Then instead of hardcoding the values, point to the dimensions and get your value from there. I'll post a code snippet for it in a minute.

Comment: There is no attribute for android:textsize in spinner.

Comment: The textSize is in the `TextView` that's being used as a `Spinner` layout. In your case, `R.layout.my_spinner_style.xml`

Comment: Working solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409871/how-to-increase-spinner-item-font-size