# Spinner Data Contents are not Visible

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner, android-spinner

I have a spinner. I have retrieved my contents in the SPINNER from the database and bind it to the Spinner.
But my problem is the Background-color of the pop up of the the Spinner window is white and also the font color for the contents is also white.
So I am not able to view the contents in the window apart from selected.

How to set the font color for the Spinner ?

Below is the Activity Code:

I have a spinner. I have bind my contents in the SPINNER from the array to the Spinner.

```
String bloodgroups[]={
"A +ve" "B +ve"
};
Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,bloodgroups);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But my problem is the Background-color of the pop up of the the Spinner window is white and also the font color for the contents is also white.
So I am not able to view the contents in the window apart from selected.

How to set the font color for the Spinner ?

Below is the  file attached :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tc"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="false"
        android:text="Enter Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:typeface="monospace" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Date of Birth"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnseldate"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Date" />

    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Blood Group"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtadd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter ContactNo. "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit Details" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Details" />

</LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Below is the  file attached :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/tc"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:freezesText="false"
        android:text="Enter Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:typeface="monospace" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Date of Birth"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtdate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="date" />



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnseldate"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Select Date" />

    </TableRow>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select Blood Group"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Address"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtadd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter ContactNo. "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtno"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnadd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit Details" />




    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btndisplay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show Details" />

</LinearLayout>    
</ScrollView>
```

[image]

Comment: I have added <xml> content.
Kindly please review it.

Comment: Have you tried the user: Ram Kiran's answer?

Comment: Changing the spinner font color refer the fallowing 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361604/how-to-change-the-spinner-font-color

Comment: yes I have tried user: Ram Kiran's suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: its due to the layout you are using for spinner (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item) try using this  for further help please provide the code snippet you are using for spinner

Comment: thanks @droidhot.. your suggestion worked. thanks a ton..

REGARDS :)

Comment: @droidhot:

Following code worked for me:

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String> this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,bloodgroups);

Comment: thats fine then it was due to the layout you ysed erlier for populating the spinner-- thnx

Comment: @droidhot yes absolutely true.

Comment: Let me guess: you target a newer API, maybe use Holo themes and on devices running Android 2.x, you get this behavior? That's exactly what I am facing. On Android 3+ it looks fine, black text on white background, on older devices same problem. The spinner is gray with white text, but when you click it, the list is white on white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create you custom adapter with  the creation of views in drop down list:

```
static class CustomArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>
{
    public CustomArrayAdapter(Context ctx, T [] objects)
    {
        super(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, objects);
    }

    //other constructors

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        //we know that simple_spinner_item has android.R.id.text1 TextView:         

        /* if(isDroidX) {*/
            TextView text = (TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setTextColor(Color.RED);//choose your color :)         
        /*}*/

        return view;

    }
}
```

And to use:

```
 this.mAdapter = new CustomArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this, bloodgroups);
```

Answer (score 0):

**simple_spinner_item.xml**

```
<TextView
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/text1"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#000"
   android:gravity="center_vertical"
   android:padding="20dp"
   android:textSize="25dp"
   android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>
```

and in your activity

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(this,R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
//adapter.add();====> Add items to the adapter here
spinner.setAdapter(adapterGender);
```