# How to set the items' text color in Spinner Android

Tags: android, android-layout, text, colors, spinner

I'm having problems with setting text color for the Spinner. I've seen few examples but most have ArrayAdapter and String array from `strings.xml` in `res folder` as my Spinner's items are retrieved from SQLite Database so I think it may not help.

Here are my Spinner's codes PersonalInformation.java

```
public class PersonalInformation extends Activity
{
    EditText txtLikes, txtDislikes, txtType, txtDate;
    Button btnView, btnBack;
    Spinner nameSpinner;    

    final Context context = this;

    private int namesSpinnerId;        

    LikesDBAdapter likeDB = new LikesDBAdapter(this);
    DislikesDBAdapter dlikeDB = new DislikesDBAdapter(this);


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.info);

        BuddyDBAdapter buddyDB = new BuddyDBAdapter(this);
        buddyDB.open();

        Cursor friendsCursor = buddyDB.getAllNames();
        startManagingCursor(friendsCursor); 

        String[] from = new String[]{BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_NAME};
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.name};

        SimpleCursorAdapter friendsCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, friendsCursor, from, to);
        friendsCursorAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        nameSpinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.nameSpinner);
        nameSpinner.setAdapter(friendsCursorAdapter);
        //buddyDB.close();


        nameSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
            {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id)
                 {
                     Cursor c = (Cursor)parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                     namesSpinnerId = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(BuddyDBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
                 }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
        buddyDB.close();
```

And, these are Spinner's layout codes in info.xml

```
<Spinner
        style="@style/SpinnerStyle"
        android:id="@+id/nameSpinner"        
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/friends_prompt"
        android:textColor="@color/green" />
```

Please help me with how to set the items text color in Spinner. 
I'll appreciate any help provided. Thanks.! =)

Comment: Please check this link . http://stackoverflow.com/a/6661762/614807

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Custom ArrayAdapter or Custom Spinner.

Have you seen http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/02/20/how-to-create-custom-layout-for-your-spinner-in-android-or-customizable-spinner-2/?

Answer (score 9):

Create a xml file for your spinner item. and put it in layout folder

```
spinner_view.xml:


<TextView  
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:gravity="left"  
  android:textColor="@color/green"         
/>
```

and finally in your code.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_view,yourList);
```

Comment: Still no color change.. :(

Answer (score 0):

modify the text color create a new xml file in your res/layout folder

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/spinnerText" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#2f4f4f" 
    android:textSize="20dp" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"/>
```

and call adapter similar to like this :

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spinner_array,
                R.layout.spinner_text);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the source code of simple_spinner_drowdown_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
/* //device/apps/common/assets/res/any/layout/simple_spinner_item.xml
**
** Copyright 2008, The Android Open Source Project
**
** Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); 
** you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. 
** You may obtain a copy of the License at 
**
**     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 
**
** Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
** distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
** WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. 
** See the License for the specific language governing permissions and 
** limitations under the License.
*/
-->
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

The problem here is ?android:attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight is not public, but it seems it is 48 dip or 64dip:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/414c4984fdbb03b688bb5c3c76d20100fce3d067%5E1..414c4984fdbb03b688bb5c3c76d20100fce3d067/