# Change Spinner style programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I need to implement function of changing the application theme up on button click. 
I have already changed successfully style of buttons, edittexts and textviews. But faced the problem of changing style for `Spinner`.

The only successful change is change of background color:

```
spinnerRoutes.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.dark_theme_spinner_background);
```

**BUT** only background of title row changed. I need also to **change textColor of rows and items**, and **background of spinner rows**.

I have already tried alot of similar stackoverflow solutions but none of them worked.

*Is it even possible to change style of spinner programatically?*

Comment: You have to use some libraries for customized spinners.

Comment: Click the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361604/how-to-change-the-spinner-font-color

Hope that's helpful.

Comment: @HasmukhBarochiya can you recommend any?

Comment: Try this http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/07/18/customizing-a-spinner-in-android/

Answer (score 4):

If u want to give customize the drop down menu of the spinner u need to override the getView function in adapter class. And also if u want to control the text that appears on the Spinnner u need to this spinner.onItemSelectedListener() and modify the text view in the call back method

sample code for customizing spinner drop down menu:

```
     @Override
        public View getDropDownView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            /**The Adapter's view to be supplied for the spinner when constructing a spinner. */
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView listView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            listView .setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(fontBack_BgnColor));

            listView .setHeight((int) heightPixels);
            listView .setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            listView .setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 20);
            listView .setTextColor(Color.parseColor(fontColor));
            listView .setText(super.getItem(position));
            return view;
        }
```

Customizing spinner text(text that appears on top of the spinner):

```
@Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                ((TextView) view).setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 25);
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor(spinnerTextColor));

            }
```

Comment: You see, I have already customized it like that when was creating. Imagine its in white colors. And now I want to change its colors to dark ones. But how?

Comment: What should i imagine as white color, specify the view(spinner background or drop down menu background).

Answer (score 3):

The other guys are right when it comes to fully customizing the items in the spinner.
But if the only thing you need to change is the style of the text in the items (meaning you still want a text view but with say different font, color, gravity) then you only need to pass the adapter a custom item layout:

This is how your adapter should look like:

```
spinner.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.custom_item, data)
```

where custom_item is an xml layout file that you create as follow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:id="@android:id/text1"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:textColor="@android:color/red"
         android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
         android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
         android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

Just make sure that the text view is the one and only view in that xml, and that its id is as specified above, so the default adapter can recognize it.

Hope that helped.