# Spinner text color

Tags: android, xml, spinner

I want to have different text color on my Spinners dropdown-list and the standard text of the item you have selected.

The standard text color of the Spinner is white and so is the text color on the popup dropdown list. The problem is that the background on the Spinner popup is also white, so I can't see the white text on the white background. I do want to keep the background white and the text color of the item you see when you haven't expanded your dropdown list to be white but the textcolor of the items in the dropdown-list to be black.

This is the code for the Spinner:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
android:id="@+id/editSpinnerWorksites"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/editTextProfileLastName"
android:textColor="@color/white_base"
android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
android:spinnerMode="dialog"
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"/>
```

And this is the code for the custom textview of the spinner

```
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_view
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start|center"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:drawablePadding="13dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: Read [this Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361604/how-to-change-the-spinner-font-color) but you should put a conditional statement for setcolor based on position to have different colors.

Comment: You can try [this](https://github.com/jaredrummler/MaterialSpinner) library. This looks good.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom layout for spinner.

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_spinner_item, list);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.custom_dropdown_item);
```

custom_spinner_item

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:id="@android:id/text1"
style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:textAlignment="inherit"
android:textColor="@color/red"/>
```

You can declare same as for drop down list.

I hope your problem will solved.